# Is it possible to egrep these symmetrical expressions over {0,1}

Tags: grep

The goal is to use solely egrep to match expressions where *n* occurrences of 0 are followed by exactly *n* occurrences of 1 and where no 0 follows a 1.

e.g.

```
01
000111
000000111111
```

but not:

```
001
011
00011
```

etc.

Intuitively, this doesn't seem achievable due to the matchable expressions not being of fixed length. But perhaps I'm missing a feature of egrep that could be useful with this?

Comment: 0 doesn't follow 1 in either of those examples and how many occurrences does `n` amount to? Edit your question and give an example of the contents of the file and the expected output.

Comment: @NasirRiley They mean where `n` is fixed. i.e. the same number of `0`s and `1`s.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this, short of hard-coding, e.g. `(01|0011|…)`, which seems like cheating.

Comment: @NasirRiley "no 0 follows a 1" i.e all matched expressions have all the 0s before the 1s. I have already given a set of matched and not-matched expressions

Comment: @Sparhawk Same here. If he just wanted to return all lines where 0 doesn't follow 1 then that would be easy. There may be a Perl or Python module that can do it but I can't devise a way in `bash`.

Comment: Not really `egrep`, but it is possible to use pcre expressions to match the symmetrical expressions, since pcre supports [recursive patterns](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#SEC23). You can use `grep -P '^(0(?1)*1)$'` to match your specific expressions (`egrep` doesn't take a `-P`, it complains about conflicting matchers, justifiably.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick overview of some CS concepts:

- [Automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory) accept strings that belong to a "language", [generated by a "grammar."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar#The_Chomsky_hierarchy)
- Regular expressions (in theory) are equivalent to (deterministic or non-deterministic) [finite automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) (DFA/NFA). So, given a regex like `0*1*`, there are DFA and NFA that can accept strings matching that regex.
- Finite automata are strictly less powerful than [pushdown automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) (PDA). The class of languages that PDA accept are generated by [context-free grammars (CFG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language).
- The strings you're looking at - `0n1n` - are generated by the CFG: `S -> 0S1 | ε` (loosely, given a starting string, you can generate a string with `0` and `1` to either side of the original string, or nothing - so it lets you generate `01`, `0011`, etc.).

While grep (extended or otherwise) has features that go beyond the "regular expressions" mentioned above, such as back-references, I don't believe any of those extend it to being as powerful as a PDA.

It can be proven that `S -> 0S1 | ε` is not regular by using [the pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages), but I don't have proof of grep's features making it able (or unable) to accept CFGs. However, the Wikipedia article on [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non-regular_languages) has this to say (bold mine):

> Many features found in virtually all modern regular expression
>   libraries provide an expressive power that far exceeds the regular
>   languages. For example, many implementations allow grouping
>   subexpressions with parentheses and recalling the value they match in
>   the same expression (backreferences). This means that, among other
>   things, a pattern can match strings of repeated words like "papa" or
>   "WikiWiki", called squares in formal language theory. The pattern for
>   these strings is `(.+)\1`.
>
> The language of squares is not regular, **nor is it context-free**, due to
>   the pumping lemma. However, pattern matching with an unbounded number
>   of backreferences, as supported by numerous modern tools, is still
>   context sensitive. <sup>[33]</sup>
>
> [33]: Cezar Câmpeanu and Kai Salomaa, and Sheng Yu (Dec 2003). "A Formal Study of Practical Regular Expressions". International Journal of Foundations of Computer Science. 14 (6): 1007–1018. doi:10.1142/S012905410300214X. Theorem 3 (p.9)

So, I'd say it's safe to say `grep` can't match `0n1n` by itself.

Comment: Not without an outer loop that loops from 1 to `n`.